# Why is html2canvas not exporting my JavaScript workspace?

Tags: javascript, html, interface, html2canvas

I'm making an workspace where you can adjust divs with javascript by width, left and height. But whenever I try to export the main ID (the workspace for the user). html2canvas does not detect its content. I'm able to convert the paramater divs with html2canvas. But not the main ID that I need to convert? Can someone help me out? Is it because I adjust the divs with Javascript? I've put the code below. Thanks in advance!

I've put the html2canvas function at the bottom of the HTML page to make it more clear. The JavaScript file is just filled with the parameters of my interface.

The code that I'm talking about that's not working is:

> ```
> <script>
>     html2canvas(document.querySelector("#main")).then(canvas => {
>         document.body.appendChild(canvas)
>     });
> </script>
> ```

```js
document.onclick = function(){
      //Breedte vlak 1
      var vlak2Left = -5;
      var vlak3Left = 68;
      var vlak4Left = 55;

      //Hoogtes
      var sliderValue2 = document.getElementById("hoogte1").value;
      var sliderValue6 = document.getElementById("hoogte4").value;
      var sliderValue8 = document.getElementById("hoogteCanvas").value;
      var sliderValue10 = document.getElementById("hoogte23").value;



      //Breedtes
      var sliderValue1 = document.getElementById("breedte1").value;
      var sliderValue3 = document.getElementById("breedte2").value;
      var sliderValue4 = document.getElementById("breedte3").value;
      var sliderValue7 = document.getElementById("breedte4").value;
      var sliderValue9 = document.getElementById("breedteCanvas").value;



      //X-meter
      var sliderValue5 = document.getElementById("xmeter3").value;

      var vlak2Total = Number(vlak2Left)+Number(sliderValue1);
      var vlak3Total = Number(vlak3Left)+Number(sliderValue1)+Number(sliderValue3)-Number(sliderValue5);
      var vlak4Total = Number(vlak4Left)+Number(sliderValue1)+Number(sliderValue3)+Number(sliderValue4)-Number(sliderValue5);

       document.getElementById("VLAK1").style.width = sliderValue1 + "px";
       document.getElementById("VLAK2").style.left = vlak2Total + "px";
       document.getElementById("VLAK3").style.left = vlak3Total + "px";
       document.getElementById("VLAK4").style.left = vlak4Total + "px";

      //Hoogte vlak 1
      document.getElementById("VLAK1").style.height = sliderValue2 + "px";

      //Breedte vlak 2
      document.getElementById("VLAK2").style.width = sliderValue3 + "px";
      document.getElementById("VLAK3").style.left = vlak3Total + "px";

      //Hoogte vlak 2+3
      document.getElementById("VLAK2").style.height = sliderValue10 + "px";
      document.getElementById("VLAK3").style.height = sliderValue10 + "px";


      //Breedte vlak 3
      document.getElementById("VLAK3").style.width = sliderValue4 + "px";
      document.getElementById("VLAK4").style.left = vlak4Total + "px";

      //X-meter vlak 3
      document.getElementById("VLAK3").style.right = sliderValue5 + "px";

      //Hoogte vlak 4
      document.getElementById("VLAK4").style.height = sliderValue6 + "px";

      //Breedte vlak 4
      document.getElementById("VLAK4").style.width = sliderValue7 + "px";

      //Hoogte canvas
      document.getElementById("main").style.height = sliderValue8 + "px";

      //Breedte canvas
      document.getElementById("main").style.width = sliderValue9 + "px";


      //Values tonen
      document.getElementById("valueBreedte1").innerHTML = sliderValue1;
      document.getElementById("valueHoogte1").innerHTML = sliderValue2;
      document.getElementById("valueBreedte2").innerHTML = sliderValue3;
      document.getElementById("valueBreedte3").innerHTML = sliderValue4;
      document.getElementById("valueXmeter3").innerHTML = "-" + sliderValue5;
      document.getElementById("valueHoogte4").innerHTML = sliderValue6;
      document.getElementById("valueBreedte4").innerHTML = sliderValue7;
      document.getElementById("canvasHoogte").innerHTML = sliderValue8;
      document.getElementById("canvasBreedte").innerHTML = sliderValue9;

}
```

```css
html {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#main {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* width: 1860px;*/
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.397);
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.parameters1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.parameters2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.parameters3 {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.parameters4 {
    grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
}

.parameters5 {
    grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6;
}

#VLAK1,
#VLAK2,
#VLAK3,
#VLAK4 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}

#VLAK1 {
    background-color: #e28e8e;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#VLAK2 {
    background-color: #f3de7f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 95px;
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    z-index: -2;
}

#VLAK3 {
    background-color: rgb(176, 241, 168);
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 269px;
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    z-index: -3;

}

#VLAK4 {
    background-color: #c3c3c3;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 356px;
    z-index: -4;

}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

.slidecontainer {
    width: 10%;
    /* Width of the outside container */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>


    <title>4 VLAKKEN</title>
</head>

<body>
        <!--SLIDERS-->
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="parameters1">
                <p>Breedte vlak 1:</p>
                <p id="valueBreedte1">100</p>
                <input type="range" id="breedte1" value="100" min="100" max="600">
                <br><br>
                <p>Hoogte vlak 1:</p>
                <p id="valueHoogte1">300</p>
                <input type="range" id="hoogte1" value="300" min="173" max="600">
            </div>
            <div class="parameters2">
                <p>Breedte vlak 2:</p>
                <p id="valueBreedte2">100</p>
                <input type="range" id="breedte2" value="100" min="100" max="300">
                <br><br>
                <p>Hoogte vlak 2+3:</p>
                <p id="valueHoogte23">300</p>
                <input type="range" id="hoogte23" value="300" min="300" max="600">
            </div>
            <div class="parameters3">
                <p>Breedte vlak 3:</p>
                <p id="valueBreedte3">100</p>
                <input type="range" id="breedte3" value="100" min="100" max="300">
                <br><br>
                <p>X-meter vlak 3:</p>
                <p id="valueXmeter3">-0</p>
                <input type="range" id="xmeter3" value="0" min="0" max="200">
            </div>
            <div class="parameters4">
                <p>Breedte vlak 4:</p>
                <p id="valueBreedte4">100</p>
                <input type="range" id="breedte4" value="100" min="100" max="600">
                <br><br>
                <p>Hoogte vlak 4:</p>
                <p id="valueHoogte4">300</p>
                <input type="range" id="hoogte4" value="300" min="0" max="600">
            </div>
            <div class="parameters5">
                <p>Breedte canvas:</p>
                <p id="canvasBreedte">600</p>
                <input type="text" id="breedteCanvas" value="600" min="0" max="1860">
                <br><br>
                <p>Hoogte canvas:</p>
                <p id="canvasHoogte">600</p>
                <input type="text" id="hoogteCanvas" value="600" min="0" max="600">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div ID="main">
            <div id="VLAK1"></div>
            <div id="VLAK2"></div>
            <div id="VLAK3"></div>
            <div id="VLAK4"></div>
        </div>
    <script>
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#main")).then(canvas => {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A shoot into the dark: Your javascript code runs only after a mouse click, while html2canvas js called close to end of page rendering.

Comment: The Javascript in the .js file shouldn't affect the html2canvas. The onclick function is only for the parameters of my interface. The Javascript script that should affect the canvas2html is at the bottom of the html file, so I don't think the onclick function in the .js file matters. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: Then be more specific so misunderstandings can be better avoided.

Comment: I edited it to make it clear. Thanks for the feedback